# Kohana validation from controller

Tags: php, validation, kohana

I want to try to set validation rules from controller, in fact, I know that in Zend Framework is something like SetRequired and AllowEmpty, exist something like in Kohana?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make your question more clear to us.

Comment: Hard to understand the question but you can start with the documentation if you haven't seen it already: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/security/validation